# Umbrella term for newspapers, magazines, news websites

Tags: word-request

What is the umbrella term for newspapers, magazines, news and investigative websites?

Is it 'publication'? It seems so, but Oxford Living Dictionaries (or Lexico, as it's now called) doesn't support it. What is the English analog for Russian 'издание'?

Comment: You mean "media"?

Comment: It's uncountable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a couple fundamental missteps in your research.

1) Never rely on a single dictionary to confirm your suspicions about a word. A single dictionary definition can rarely capture all nuances of a word. From Wordnik:

> **[publication](https://www.wordnik.com/words/publication)** (*noun*) An issue of printed or electronic matter, such as a book or magazine, offered for distribution or sale.

2) I would argue that the Lexico entry **does** support your initial hunch. After all, it says:

> **[publication](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/publication)** (*noun*) A book or journal issued for public sale.

but if we look up *journal* on the same website, we find:

> **[journal](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/journal)** (*noun*) A newspaper or magazine that deals with a particular subject or professional activity.

So, if you wanted an umbrella term for newspapers and magazines, I'd argue that you could use *publications*. If you wanted the term to include news websites, you might be able to use *news journals* as well.

Comment: No, I need a term that covers both printed and internet outlets. Lexico doesn't include news websites in its definition of 'publication'. 'News journal' is something way off. I never came across it, let alone applied to online newspapers

Comment: @SergeyZ - Well, as the definition I've included here says: An issue of printed **or electronic matter**. So internet outlets can certainly be under the definition of _publication_. No dictionary will list every type of possible publication in its definition. As for never hearing of _news journal_, well, try [this Google query](https://www.google.com/search?q="is+a+news+journal"). You'll find quotes like this one: _If you are familiar with the Mirror, you know it is a news journal from the United Kingdom_.